# Sequelize n:m association join table with attributes

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to build the models for a n:m association in Node JS using Sequelize.
The image who follows shows what I am trying to map in the backend:

[image: Imgur]

Using the official documentation, the models that I have defined are the following:

```
let Dashboards = sequelize.define('Dashboards', {
    name: DataType.STRING(30),
    category: DataType.TINYINT(2)
}, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    timestamps: false,
    tableName: 'dashboards'
});

Dashboards.associate = function (models) {
    Dashboards.belongsToMany(models.Charts, {
        through: {
            unique: false,
            model: models.DashboardCharts
        },
        foreignKey: 'dashboardId'
    });
};

let Charts = sequelize.define('Charts', {
    type: DataType.INTEGER(5),
    title: DataType.STRING(30),
}, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    timestamps: false,
    tableName: 'charts'
});

Charts.associate = function (models) {
    Charts.belongsToMany(models.Dashboards, {
        through: {
            unique: false,
            model: models.DashboardCharts,
        },
        foreignKey: 'chartId'
    });
};
let DashboardCharts = sequelize.define('DashboardCharts', {
    title: {
        type: DataType.STRING(30)
    },
    color: {
        type: DataType.STRING(7)
    }
}, {
freezeTableName: true,
    timestamps: false,
    tableName: 'dashboard_charts'
});
```

Now, if using DashboardCharts I try to join the table with Dashboards in this way:

```
DashboardCharts.findAll({
    include: [
        {
            model: Dashboard,
            required: true,
        }
    ]
})
```

I got this error: **SequelizeEagerLoadingError: Dashboards is not associated to DashboardCharts!**
What am I doing wrong? Thanks to anyone who could help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: I was wrong doing the association. With the current configuration, I could only ask for Dashboard's charts or vice versa. The right solution is to set belongsTo from the join table, as it follows:

```
let Dashboards = sequelize.define('Dashboards', {
    name: DataType.STRING(30),
    category: DataType.TINYINT(2)
}, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    timestamps: false,
    tableName: 'dashboards'
});

let Charts = sequelize.define('Charts', {
    type: DataType.INTEGER(5),
    title: DataType.STRING(30),
}, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    timestamps: false,
    tableName: 'charts'
});


let DashboardCharts = sequelize.define('DashboardCharts', {
    dashboard_id: {
        type: DataType.INTEGER(5),
        primaryKey: true
    },
    chart_id: {
        type: DataType.INTEGER(5),
        primaryKey: true
    },
    title: {
        type: DataType.STRING(30)
    },
    color: {
        type: DataType.STRING(7)
    }
}, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    timestamps: false,
    tableName: 'dashboard_charts'
});

DashboardCharts.associate = function (models) {
    DashboardCharts.belongsTo(models.Dashboards, {
        foreignKey: 'dashboard_id',
        sourceKey: models.Dashboards.id
    });

    DashboardCharts.belongsTo(models.Charts, {
        foreignKey: 'chart_id',
        sourceKey: models.Charts.id
    });
};
```